# Why does www.twitter.com return a different IP address sometimes with InetAddress/getHostAddress()?

Tags: java, facebook, twitter, ip

Why www.twitter.com returns a different IP address sometimes I run this java code?

```
  InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("www.twitter.com");
  System.out.println("www.twitter.com" + " : " + host.getHostAddress());
```

Other websites mostly return the same IP address ie. www.facebook.com always returns 179.60.193.3

Yahoo.com always for instance returns  203.84.216.121

Comment: Also when I use that IPadress it does not direct me to twitter.com actual website (when I type it in to a browser)

Comment: Which values do you get back?

Comment: 199.59.149.198 , 199.59.150.47, 199.59.149.230 for example

Comment: it is perhaps not your code, it is something from the dns server, but what exactly it is I am not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `www.twitter.com` is assigned multiple IPv4 addresses.

A hostname can map to multiple IP addresses.  Which one you get when you look up a hostname depends on a lot of configuration specifics in DNS.

And for what it's worth, an IP address can also have more than one host name assigned to it.

Comment: Is there a way I can see how many  IPv4 addresses twitter.com is assigned?

Comment: @PatrickLee `man dig` (if you're on a Unix-based system) should lead you in the right direction. Windows has `nslookup` I think.

Comment: Your results can also depend on the DNS server you're querying.  Just Google `dns servers` and you can find a lot of other DNS servers you can query.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely due to **DNS Round Robin**. Basically, there is more than just one A-Record for the name "twitter.com" and your client dynamically choses one of the provided Records and uses it. The used record can switch frequently.